# Null в Dictionary<T, V>

Tags: c#, null, словари

Записываю значение в словарь, и даже при моментальной проверке там оказывается `Null`:

```
_attacks.Add(TestAttack.Name, new TestAttack());
GD.Print(_attacks[TestAttack.Name]);
```

`_attacks` - `Dictionary<string, Attack>`
`TestAttack` наследуется от `Attack`

[image: Godot выводит данную ошибку]

Comment: `TestAttack.Name` - это строка? Она не меняется?

Comment: @tym32167 Строка, и вообще константная, так что я уверен в том, что она не меняется

Comment: _attacks - это поле которое тоже не меняется? Спрашиваю, так как то, что вы описываете, не укладывается в поведение словаря и потому очевидно, что вы что то делаете не так

Comment: возможно ли, что `GD.Print()` будет всегда выводить null? Поставьте точку останова на нем и поглядите в дебаге что находится внутри словаря

Comment: Увы, дебага нет, но я могу вывести конкретную ошибку, который выдаёт мне Godot (добавлю в сам вопрос)

Comment: из того, что вы показали, не следует, что словарь работает неверно. NRE может быть где угодно. У вас есть стектрейс?

Comment: *Это* не может делать *то*.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре все нормально. У Вас есть какие-то неинициализированные поля в свежесозданном экземпляре `TestAttack`.